# How to disable Ctrl + Alt + Del in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to disable the Ctrl+Alt+Del shortcut because it interferes with the same shortcut in my VirtualBox's Windows. How can I do this?

I tried to remove it from keyboard shortcuts in settings but it didn't help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190631/disabling-control-alt-delete-shutdown-is-not-working ?? (q is about <12 but the accepted answer is 12.04) It seems to work as stated in that topic ...

Comment: @Rinzwind that's what I did and didn't help at all... the shorcut makes unity to get the focus back - which is quite weird

Comment: In what way does it interfere? In a VirtualBox you type Host-key + DEL to get the desired effect.

Comment: @guntbert when i press the shortcut in vbox, the vm loses focus and it goes back to the ubuntu... and nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask again: Which shortcut? Ctrl+Alt+Del or HostKey+DEL? (HostKey usually is the right STRG).

Comment: @guntbert ctrl+alt+del... i didn't say anything about hostkey+del

Comment: But I did in my comment above (#3), I thought you were referring to that comment.

Comment: @guntbert no, i stick with my original question all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send Ctrl+Alt+Del to VirtualBox by pressing those exact keys on the keyboard, even if they are not reassigned in Unity.  You can send the Ctrl+Alt+Del combination in VirtualBox at least two ways:

1. Click the "Machine" menu and choose "Insert Ctrl-Alt-Del"
2. Press the "Host key" and the "Del" key.

The host key is usually the Right Ctrl key, but you can change that to be something else.  If you have not changed it, try pressing Ctrl-Del in your VirtualBox to send Ctrl+Alt+Del.  Make sure you use the Right Ctrl key and not the Left one.

This is detailed further in the [VirtualBox user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) in the section titled [Typing Special Characters](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp14789648).